# Añadir descripción a métodos/atributos en C# (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, studio, visual

Me gustaría saber como (si es que es posible), al definir una clase propia, con sus atributos y sus métodos, poder añadirles un texto de descripción para que al usar los metodos y atributos mas tarde, aparezca dicha descripción; como aparece con las clases "propias" de .NET:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es que, al crear una clase de biblioteca (o libreria), los futuros desarrolladores sepan lo que hacen los metodos a la hora de usarlos.

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda!!
Un saludo!!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 2):

Para darle información al desarrollador tenés que agregar sobre el method/property ***Tags References***!.

Hay muchos tipos de tags, dentro de los cuales uno es el ***"summary"***. Pero se pueden usar otros para la visualización de ejemplo y demás ayudas.

```
public class Rectangulo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Esta es la descripción de la altura del rectángulo
    /// </summary>
    public int Heigth { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Esta es la descripción del ancho del rectángulo
    /// </summary>
    public int Width { get; set; }

}
```

[image: Descripcioprop]

> Documentación oficial de Microsoft:
>   [https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/summary](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/codedoc)

Espero que se sea de ayuda!.
Saludos! :)

Comment: podrias agregar (si lo tenes) un link a la documentacion oficial de esto.. porque se pueden hacer mas cosas!!! mira por favor [answer].. Gracias por el aporte!

Comment: Muchisimas gracis!!

Comment: Gracias por los consejos!, ahí lo edite un poco :)